# Assembly (masm): Inline asm, transfer offset to esi

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, inline-assembly

I wrote a standalone .asm procedure which I can use with my C++ console application. The task is to determine whether the word is a palindrome. The procedure has two arguments. The first one being the starting address (first element) of char array and the second one representing the number of elements of that array. The result is 1 for palindrome and 0 for non-palindrome.

```
; Prototype in .cpp: extern int method(char* string, int number);

public method

.code
method proc
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
pushf
push ebx
push ecx
push edx
push esi
mov eax, 1
mov ecx, [ebp+12]
mov esi, [ebp+8]
mov edi, [ebp+8]
add edi, ecx
sub edi, 1
shr ecx, 1

while_loop:
    mov dl, byte ptr[edi]
    mov dh, byte ptr[esi]
    cmp dl, dh
    je continue
    mov eax, 0
    jmp notPal

    continue:
    inc esi
    dec edi
loop while_loop

notPal:

pop esi
pop edx
pop ecx
pop ebx
popf
pop ebp
ret
method endp
end
```

That works just fine, so I wanted to rewrite the same code and use it within my source code in Visual Studio (C++) as **inline assembly function**.

```
int method(char* string, int number){
    __asm{
        mov eax, offset string
        mov esi, eax  // Error C2415 Improper operand type

    }

}
```

I tried to move array's offset to esi/edi in more than one way and couldn't do it. Is this possible with inline assembly?

Comment: `string` is a local variable on the stack, so you can't grab its offset like that. Presumably `lea eax, string` might work. The error is unlikely to be on the line you indicated, though.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. lea esi, string does the trick. You're right about the error, the line above the one I commented is causing the problem, I just placed the comment next to instruction with source-index register.